# BIGINT UNSIGNED auto increment broken with mybatis

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis, auto-increment, biginteger

So I have:

- a PK column:

  ```
  id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  ```
- a POJO Entity with an `id` field

  ```
  java.math.BigInteger id field
  ```
- an mapper insert method:

  ```
      @Insert("INSERT INTO " +
      "table_name (" +
      "created_at_ts, " +
      "updated_at_ts" +
      ") " +
      "VALUES (" +
      "UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), " +
      "UNIX_TIMESTAMP()" +
      ")")
      @Options(useGeneratedKeys = true, keyColumn = "id")
      void insert(Entity entity);
  ```
- A call to the mapper insert method like:

  ```
  commandMapper.insert(entity);
  ```

All of this works perfectly fine until a certain number of rows have been inserted successfully. I suddenly get the following error while inserting a row in a child table:

```
    org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: 
    ### Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: 
    Out of range value for column 'parent_id' at row 1
```

It looks like the result of the following is ok:

```
    SELECT Auto_increment FROM information_schema.tables WHERE 
    table_name='table';

    -> 32770
```

But the value of the BigInteger id field of the entity is wrong:

```
    System.out.println(entity.getId());

    -> -32767
```

How can I end up with a negative value in the entity POJO?

Apparently:

- using a `BigIntegerTypeHandler` does not solve the problem
- switching from a `BIGINT UNSIGNED` to an `INT UNSIGNED` and from a `java.math.BigInteger` to a `Long` fixes it.

But there might be another way?

Many thanks.

Comment: Where did you define `parent_id`, what data type does it have and where are you inserting into it?

Comment: `parent_id` is a column in a child table defined by : `parent_id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL` as well. But the problem is more around the value of the `id` field in the parent entity.

Comment: @revo asked valid questions. The problem happens when child record is inserted, so the definition of the entity, the query that is used to insert and child table definition are crucial to figure out what is the reason.

Comment: @user3173237 does this problem happen if no child records are inserted? Can you describe the whole usecase please? The puzzling thing is how insertion of child records is related to generation of the id for parent record. Id generation for parent happens when parent is created.

Comment: Child table and child entity are built the same way as the parent table and parent entity, meaning: `parent_id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL` column, and `java.math.BigInteger parent_id` field in the POJO entity. But guys, I don't get why the `id` field of the parent entity is a negative value in the first place.

Comment: @RomanKonoval, sorry it is a bit unclear. The use case is every time a row is inserted in the parent table, I get back the auto-incremented value and use it as a value for the `parent_id` column of the child table. Every time a parent record is inserted, a child record is inserted as well. hope it is a little clearer now.

Comment: It looks like mybatis erroneously uses incorrect type when fetching generated key. You may try to specify `keyProperty` in addition to or instead of `keyColumn`. Also you can try to use `@SelectKey` instead of `useGeneratedKeys`. This may give mybatis a better hint about types (or at least this will use another code path that does not have this bug)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to bump spring-jdbc and mariadb-java-client to fix this issue.